# How can I say “for dummies” in Latin?

Tags: word-request

I want to make a parody of the famous “for dummies” in Latin.

How could it be translated?

I thought *ad nulli* to mirror the French version “pour les nuls”, but I’m not sure it actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a review/comment on the other suggestions here more than a standalone answer (it started out as a comment to the answer by Kingshorsey).

First of all, ***in/ad ūsum** alicuijus* 'for use, enjoyment by X' is clearly *the* expression to go for here; another option is *alicui **dēstinātum*** 'designed, intended for X,' and the two can even be combined.

- The bare dative would make for an abruptly unfinished, un-Latin and clearly translated book title, because it normally expresses relation or ownership, while the 'goal' meaning needs to be supplied by some predicate: *liber puerīs est* 'the book belongs to the kids'; *liber puerīs cārus* 'a book dear to children'.
- *prō aliquō* would read as meaning 'a book arguing in favour of', although [it's found](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pro%20pueris%22&tbm=bks) in a few Renaissance book titles, clearly a "medieval student Latin" usage translated from German/French.

Next, on to the choice of the nominal, which with *in ūsum* will appear in the genitive case (all in *-ōrum* except *rudium, tīrōnum*), and in the dative before *dēstinātum* (all in *-īs* except *rudibus, tīrōnibus*). And if you're using the latter with another Latin noun, it will need to agree in gender as well, e.g. *liber...dēstinātu**s.*** If not, leave it neuter:

- *imperītī* was my initial thought, but it's opposed to *perītī/doctī*, while *dummies* are opposed rather to *geniuses* or even more so to *sharpies.* While the Latin word is circumspect and totally lacking any connotation of subpar intellectual abilities - although it can be used disparagingly, of course.
- Unlike the former word, I had't seen *rudēs* used on its own, and a [google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20usum%20rudium%22&tbm=bks) gives only a couple of occurrences where it isn't joined at least with another synonym. This is because its use in reference to people is felt as a metaphor from fresh shoots; consequently *rudēs puerī* is its usual collocation.
- *ignārī* would seem to be the best option combining enough contempt with a possibility of substantival use; however, [a search for "in usum ignarorum"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20usum%20ignarorum%22&tbm=bks) nets nothing at all. Plus, it's way too blunt.
- *stultī* is quite a bit milder than 'fool' or even 'stupid', rather corresponding to 'silly, naïve' or indeed the almost gentle 'dummy'. It's opposed to *sapiēns* and so in principle can be applied to anyone whom you would be hesitant to put in the latter category. All in all, an option to consider, but lacking a certain *je ne sais quoi.*
- *in ūsum tīrōnum* is without question the standard expression in book titles, but it corresponds to the neutral 'for beginners, novices'.

---

So do I have any better suggestions? I noticed that Cicero metaphorically used the pairing *peregrīnī atque advenae* to refer to outsiders to a certain discipline. And  the ultimate word for an outsider lacking all familiarity with the customs and culture of the host nation is, of course, ***barbarus,*** a word which besides referring to non-Greeks or Latins (i.e. all cultural foreigners) is also synonymous to *rudis, incultus* and thus standing in opposition to *hūmānus, ērudītus.* I think therefore that ***in ūsum barbarōrum*** would play nicely on this Roman cultural opposition, being both ironic (since that opposition is - ehem - *foreign* to, and in fact targetting most of us) and unironic at the same time (since we can understand and appreciate it), a tension very much like that in the English 'for dummies'. As such, I think it would make for an excellent translation.

Apart from that, there actually is a specialised condescending word for someone who belongs to the uneducated *vulgus,* synonymous to *indoctus, illitterātus,* and that word is ***idiōta*** ([see Forcellini](http://lexica.linguax.com/forc2.php?searchedLG=idiota) to get a better sense for its usage and connotations). Its closest English equivalent is 'layman', while 'idiot' is a notorious false friend. The only problem is that it's in no way humorous or colloquial, but rather haughtily educated. It would be phrased as *in ūsum idiōtārum* and *idiōtīs dēstinātum.*

Comment: Unbrutal_Russian: The title, "For Barbarians", would certainly attract attention and generate some jokes. In the contemporary (English) mind it would conjure-up fierce imagery: everything from smelly, hairy, hysterical German tribesmen charging a Roman phalanx, to hordes of rampaging football hooligans. And to the Roman mind? Are you sure about this? I thought Joonas's, "tironibus", was a good one: in the dat. pl. it's not necessarily neuter. There are other, gentler, ways of saying "for the inexperienced" e.g. "imperitis"; "inexpertis"; "inscitis" (Oxford).

Comment: One can read a lot about the Romano-Greek concept of foreigners, but 'forgeigners' is essentially what *barbarī* refers to, only less in reference to ethnicity (as in our nationalist age) and more in reference to (literary) culture. The imagery that the word conjures up for us rather speaks about our own conceptions of all the ancient peoples who weren't Roman or Greek. There's been a lot of effort in the academia to modify these conceptions.—The "gentler" ways have the problems that I describe - they're too circumspect and involve no humour or double take; the latter is what makes the English

Comment: As I say, the bare dative is not used in Latin book titles, and would look like clumsy translationese. Someone who's translating a book title into Latin has the luxury of having unlimited access to the vast early printed book output in Latin, and there's no excuse for not knowing how the target audience is expressed in the language.—There's no neuter *tīrō,* it's an animate noun, so it's not the gender that's the problem, it's that the bare dative gives an abruptly unfinished book title.

Comment: Unbrutal_Russian: Understood. Someone's given a "-1"; I've put it back to zero--best I can do.

Comment: @tony Yep, I've noticed that - thank you. If the person who's downvoted it is reading, I'm always interested in and open to receiving suggestions on how my answers can be improved, or what statements may require elaboration, illustration or any other support.

Comment: I personally would not be able to resist idiota, since the goal is to produce a parody book in the modern context.  Bringing to mind "idiot" is an advantage, a nod to the original "For Dummies," even though the words aren't real synonyms. I also like your suggestion of barbarus, though.

Comment: @Kingshorsey It didn't occur to me at all how the modern context actually does tip the balance towards *idiōta* - that's a very neat observation! I think part of this is that I always try and proactively avoid false friends with modern languages, and this one's notorious. Which makes me be overly cautious and overlook instances like these where in fact the "stupid" association is welcome.—Still, I have to say that in my opinion 95% of the eventual audience will not understand it the way we do, as an interlanguage pun, but will think the meaning proper to the Latin word.

Comment: Quick note modern connotations of ***idiōta*** / Eng. "idiot" in *this specific context*, i.e., a parody of the [IDG Books / Wiley Publishing *... For Dummies* reference books franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Dummies). The books actually have a fairly successful, imitative competitor, the [*Complete Idiot's Guide To...* series by Alpha Books / DK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Idiot%27s_Guides). It's not unlikely someone looking at ***idiōta*** might think of the orange books as quickly as the *For Dummies* books.

Comment: This *may* be a problem or it may just as easily being an advantage, depending on the details, on your purposes in the parody, etc.

Comment: @AlabamaScholiast Thanks for mentioning this - I think they might in a great majority of cases (given they're familiar with the competing series), but at that point it will hardly be relevant; in both cases they will be attributing the same non-existent meaning to the Latin word, but the type of book will be clear, which seems to be the main communicative intent. If one has a wide audience in mind, misinterpretation is unavoidable, and one will probably opt to avoid the use of the lookalike word altogether.

Answer (score 7):

A single passage of Cicero gives us three near synonyms worth considering:

> **imperiti** homines rerum omnium **rudes** **ignari**que (inexperienced men, unfamiliar with and ignorant of everything)

All three words denote lack of knowledge stemming from lack of experience. All three also have something of the derogatory connotation in "dummies," although raw intellectual capacity isn't at issue.

I'm partial to *rudis* because it's in the title of one of St. Augustine's treatises: *De Catechizandis Rudibus* (*Catechizing the Uninstructed*)

Whichever word you choose, you will need to use it in a particular case that depends on the form of the rest of the title. Perhaps we could riff on a classic series, *in usum Delphini* (for the use/benefit of the Dauphin).

So, Cooking for Dummies might come out *Institutiones Coquinariae, in usum Rudium*.

Answer (score 6):

One Latin word worth considering is [*tiro*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DT%3Aentry+group%3D22%3Aentry%3Dtiro1), meaning a beginner.
A beginner is not quite the same as a dummy, but perhaps close enough for many purposes.
I'd be happy to use it in a book title along the lines of "Latin for dummies".

To say "for dummies", you need the plural dative of this word: ***tironibus***.

---

Let me also comment on your suggestion *ad nulli*.
With the preposition *ad* you would need the accusative, so it would have to be *ad nullos*.
But this means "to nobody".
It's quite different to say that the audience is non-expert than to say that it is non-existent!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest expression could be, "stultis" = "for the stupid", from the adjective, "stultus". This reminds me of the amusing, "stulto stultior" = "more stupid than stupid", in which "stulto" is an ablative-of-comparison; "stultior", a comparative.

Much depends on how offensive you wish to be. Joonas's text would be entitled, "tironibus"; mine, "stultis".

Mind, some of the mistakes that I have made would consign me to the latter work.